# Custom Backbone Sync

Tags: backbone.js, synchronization

I'm trying to build a custom replacement of Backbone's `sync` with something like the following:

```
function getStuff(){
    return {"id":"1","name":"Joe"};
}
```

Then for `Backbone.sync` I have:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {

    switch(method){

        case 'read':
            getStuff();
            break;

        ...More cases...
```

I've looked through several post on replacing sync and I know I need to use `options` to handle the return, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fetches are usually async, so you should return your response to the options.success function:

```
sync : function(method, model, options) {
    if (method == 'read') {
        var yourResponse = getStuff();
        options.success && options.success(yourResponse);
    }
}
```

Backbone uses the options.success function to apply the response onto the Model. You can also provide your own options.success function:

```
yourModel.fetch({
    success : function(response) {
        // use response
    }
});
```

Note that Backbone will now run your custom success function and then its own function.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I was overthinking it - ultimately just needed to send it back in the options.